# How to work with catching errors

Tags: java, exception

I refreshing my Java skills, say we've got this code

```
public class HelloWorld extends Exception {
    public static int tenMultiplication(int x) {
        for (int i = 2; i < 11; i++) {
            System.out.println(x * i);
        }
        return x;
    }

    public static String scanExpression() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String exp = "";

        do {
            System.out.println("Please enter a number:");

            try {
                exp = scan.nextLine();
                int result = Integer.parseInt(exp);
                tenMultiplication(result);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
            }
        } while (exp.matches("-?\\d+") || exp == "exit");

        return exp;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
       scanExpression();
    }
}
```

Program logic: Program asks for an input, and draws a row of multiplication table till 10; any time you can exit by typing "exit", everything else is an error.

Every time I write an incorrect number, it will simply catch an error and exit the program. What is the best way with going about iteratively catching errors if  you consecutively type non-Ints and not "exit" to exit the program? I tried putting

```
exp = scan.nextLine();
int result = Integer.parseInt(exp);
tenMultiplication(result);
```

But when trying to write an error here, it throws the error again, which defeats the point of my try { } catch blocks.

Comment: `exp == "exit"` - See: [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Honestly, there are many good books and tutorials out there teaching such things. And unrelated: there is absolutely no point in calling a class HelloWorld to then extend Exception. Your class has to deal with exceptions - that doesn't mean at all that your example class should **be** an Exception!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to re-read the input in case NumberFormatException is caught, you can do it in a recursive way by by calling your function again

```
public static void scanExpression(Scanner scan) {

        System.out.println("Please enter a number:");

        try {
            String exp = scan.nextLine();
            if(exp.equals("exit"))
                System.exit(0);
            int result = Integer.parseInt(exp);
            tenMultiplication(result);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {scanExpression(scan);}

}

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    scanExpression(scan);
}
```

Comment: This is THE answer.

Comment: Thank you. Just checked it out and worked flawlessly. Gave me some good other ideas about how to order your code!

Answer (score 0):

After the `catch` block executes the program continues and goes to check the condition in the `while` statement. The while statement returns `false` for that condition so your program terminates. Plus you need to compare `exp` like this: `exp.equals("exit")`.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some changes I made to your loop.

```
  do {
      System.out.println("Please enter a number:");

      try {
          exp = scan.nextLine();
          int result = Integer.parseInt(exp);
          tenMultiplication(result);
      } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

      }
  } while (!exp.equals( "exit") );
```

I made your catch block empty. The reasoning is that if it does catch invalid input from the user, `"Please enter a number:"` would print twice.

Also, I modified your while loop condition. Previously you had `exp == "exit"`. This doesn't work the way you expect it to work. When comparing String values, always use `String1.equals(String2) to see if String1 and String2 are equal.